# (PHP) How to get object from HttpClient (Angular 6)

Tags: php, angular, angular-httpclient

Angular 6 :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class GetData {
    constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }
    post( ) {
      data = [ {username : 'test',password : '1234' }];
      return this.http.post('login.php' , data );
    }
}
```

PHP : login.php

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

?>
```

How can i get data from Angular 6 that is [Object] into $username , $password

**

> "$_POST" and "$_REQUEST" is not available for me.

**

Comment: do you subscribe to post function somewhere? without subscribe, your post function does nothing.

Comment: I already have that code. I try to  echo '[]' .... it work button try to echo $username , $password . it is blank value.

Comment: try to post formData:
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("test", "123");
this.http.post("login.php", formData).subscribe();

Comment: Thank you for all solutions!!. I got the solution that resolves my problem. I have to declare variable using 'php://input'  .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpParams  } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class GetData {
    constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }
    post( ) {
     let data= new HttpParams()
    .append("username", "test")
    .append("password", "1234")


      return this.http.post('login.php' , data );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Angular seems to send POSTs that end up in `php://input` instead of `$_POST`, and then you can `json_decode` them into an object and use them.

On the Angular side - I'm just tossing data at the server, I care not about the response... tried getting it going without the whole `subscribe()` thing but it wouldn't POST at all for me at that point... Note taht there is a `private http: Http` in the constructor for the TS file/component/class this is in...

```
postChatMessage(room: string, user: string, msg: string, timestamp: number) {
    var cmsg = new ChatMessage(room, msg, user, timestamp);
    return this.http.post(BASEURL + "/chat", cmsg)
        .subscribe(
        (v) => {},
        response => {},
        () => {}
        );
}
```

The PHP on the back end that handles the POST that sends - yes, I'm being lazy and just storing the whole JSON string sent plus a few other things, but easier for me to deal with for a quick school thing -

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") &&
        (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/json_service/chat") === 0)) {
    $d = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $d = json_decode($d);
    $d->timestamp = time();
    $q = "insert into json_chat values(?,?,?,?)";
    $a = array(null, time(), $d->room, json_encode($d));
    $res = executeQuery($q, $a);
    print(json_encode(array($res[0])));  // boolean fwiw
    exit;
}
```